# nav links show/hide transition is not wroking with tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css, css-transitions

i have hamburger button to show/hide nav links in small device. it works fine but i want to show/hide nav links with transition but it does not works

```
//imports
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    setIsVisible(!isVisible);
  };
  return (
    <nav className={`bg-gray-600 dark:bg-gray-950 fixed w-full top-0 z-10`}>
      <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row container p-3 justify-between align-middle max-w-screen-xl mx-auto text-center">
        <div className="relative flex">
        //header logo
          <div className="absolute right-2 md:hidden">
            {isVisible ? (
              <ImCross
                alt="hamburger"
                className="hidden max-lg:block h-9 w-9 pt-2 text-white"
                onClick={handleButtonClick}
              />
            ) : (
              <GiHamburgerMenu
                className="hidden max-lg:block h-9 w-9 pt-2 text-white"
                onClick={handleButtonClick}
              />
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="">
          <ul
            className={`flex-1 flex max-md:flex-col gap-10 font-kanit text-white align-middle  p-3 transition-all duration-500 ease-in-out ${
              isVisible ? "flex" : "max-md:hidden"
            }`}
          >
           //navlinks
            </span>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};
export default Nav;
```

tried to ask chatgpt and bard but their answer are the same.

Answer (score 0):

transition does not work on display property.
use opacity instead.

isVisible ? "opacity-100" : "max-md:opacity-0"

for more about display transition [transition-behavior(experimental)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-behavior)